# The match filter must be an expression in an object

Tags: mongodb, typescript

This is my request body:

```
{
    "filter": [{"NMUNIT": "MINI-MART GKB"}, {"KELUNIT": "311081116"}],
    "group": ["AKUN", "KELUNIT", "NMUNIT"]
}
```

This is my SecureObject class:

```
export default class SecureObjects {
    public create(key: any, value: any){
        var result = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++)
            result[key[i]] = value[i];
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is my script: https://pastebin.com/raw/rqFGgdWx

I'm getting error like: `the match filter must be an expression in an object` – why is `$match` not an object?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its because the format of a `filter` is `filter: {<your custom filter>}`. In your case it will be `"filter": {"$and":[{"NMUNIT": "MINI-MART GKB"}, {"KELUNIT": "311081116"}]}`

Comment: It still wont work, since your group will throw an error too

Comment: The error mean $match filter not "filter"

Comment: The problem why var filterData and var groupData is not object output